# Prevent duplicity to download all manifests

Tags: duplicity

I need to restore most recent duplicity backup into the clean VM. Backup interval is 1 hour. The oldest backup should be 6 months.

And every time I restore backup into clean VM duplicity downloads all the manifests and signatures. And it takes a lot of time.

I tried to find an option which will prevent this behavior, but could not. Prefixes work only for storing different backup sets inside one directory.

Answer (score 1):

It is not perfect solution, but as a result I had to use **--file-prefix** for duplicity backups.

```
BACKUP_DATE=${BACKUP_DATE:-$(date -u +%Y%m%d)}
DUPLICITY_OPTIONS="--full-if-older-than 1D --file-prefix ${BACKUP_DATE}_"
```

If you need to restore old backups, you have to specify the date of the backup explicitly:

```
# DAY="yesterday | -1 day | -1 month | etc"
DAY="-1 month"
BACKUP_DATE=$(date -u +%Y%m%d --date="${DAY}")
DUPLICITY_OPTIONS="--full-if-older-than 1D --file-prefix ${BACKUP_DATE}_"
```